# Rails console not starting after using /usr/bin/env to load environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My RoR application isn't loading properly and the first error happens when loading the environment variables `.env` file.

the script is straight forward and (should) load the .env to start the rails console:

```
basedir=/home/mapaapp/mapaapp/
cd $basedir/current
env $(cat $basedir/shared/.env | xargs) rails c
cd -
```

I got two responses as I load the script: `cat: /shared/.env: No such file or directory`, even knowing that there is a .env file in this directory and `env: #: No such file or directory` which I believe refers to /usr/bin/env, which also exists.

this app runs:

- Ubuntu 15.10 (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64)
- Rails 4.2.1
- ruby 2.2.2p95
- nginx 1.9.3
- puma 2.15.3

any idea what could be preventing `rails c` from starting? If any additional info is needed I'll be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first think I would try would be to use a string for your path (safer) and call the env executable using it's full path, since bash scripts run in sub-shells, it's possible the env command is not in the $PATH variable :

```
basedir="/home/mapaapp/mapaapp/"
cd "$basedir/current"
/usr/bin/env $(cat "$basedir/shared/.env" | xargs) rails c
cd -
```

And it seems right now you are not passing any command to xargs
Having a command in the following format :

```
$(echo 1)
```

Means to execute the command between parentheses in a subshell and return the result. So i could assign the value 1 to a variable like such :

```
a=$(echo 1)
```

So I would try modifying the line to make sure the arguments in the .env file are used :

```
/usr/bin/env $(cat "$basedir/shared/.env") | xargs rails c
```

Comment: I tried `/usr/bin/env $(cat "$basedir/shared/.env") | xargs rails c
` and received this answer:
```/usr/bin/env: #: No such file or directory
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
```